# How to improve anti scraping for S3 bucket with specific referer policy and CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront, http-referer

The current situation is that I have a **CloudFront** distribution with a **OAI** pointing to my images bucket that are served in my app. I've managed to make the bucket policy to only allow the **getObject** action from the cloudfront distribution and only to be accessed from my app's domain with the **Referer** header.

The issue is that if someone manages to fake that referer from a script they could access the images and make a scraping bot and fetch all my data. Is there any way to prevent the access even futher to only be accessible from my own app ?

App's business is a photo news market between news agencies and photographers so my aim is to have a cheap and scalable mechanisms for those restrictions as I manage a lot of photos at once, thus a presigned request for each is load intensive and using a firewall could be very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go with signed urls approach, other approach you could try  -

You can add a custom header along with traditional headers like referrer etc. - This will take care of 99% of the scraping, while there might be few scrapers who would replicate even this header, for them you can simply start blocking them.

Comment: I was wondering if I can add a policy to the bucket to only allow actions on the resources from my app's lambdas (somehow restricting the acces by the lambda's arn prefix of somehow). I'm not really sure how to do it at the moment. I'll try some things and come back with updates on this matter.